# AWS Amplify return error 403 when try to load fonts

Tags: regex, reactjs, build, aws-amplify

I have a React JS project developed on AWS Amplify but I'm having problems loading fonts and other assets.

The font used appears with error **403** at the following URL:

https://SUBDOMAIN.amplifyapp.com/src/fonts/SF-Compact/SF-Compact-Text-Regular.otf

But at the URL below the source is found:

https://SUBDOMAIN.amplifyapp.com/static/media/SF-Compact-Text-Regular.55a5fc5b.otf

I don't know if the problem is the regular expression used for Single Page Web Apps (SPA) redirects or something else since the folder searched for in the non-working URL is `src/fonts` and the correct URL is`static/media`.

I am using the standard regular expression suggested in the documentation, just included `otf`:

```
</^[^.]+$|\.(?!(css|gif|ico|jpg|js|png|txt|svg|woff|ttf|otf|map|json)$)([^.]+$)/>
```

Comment: Any updates on that, I have kind of the same problem?

Comment: Not yet. The font is loaded but the error persists.

Comment: I had to add otf to my Rewrites and redirects in app settings for /index.html